# what is special of images in cloonix? I can't use the same image in gns3

Tags: image, networking, virtual, simulation, qemu

I want to use the same images (`.qcow2` or `.img`) in cloonix and gns3 to compare their performances. In GNS3, I can use the normal images but not the images I download at the site  http://cloonix.fr/ .  In cloonix, I can use all the images but the images which I download at the other site (not at the site http://cloonix.fr/) are always red and I can not use the normal console. So I want to know if the images in cloonix are special. Why I can not use them in gns3? They both use QEMU and they use the same types.

Answer (score 0):

In cloonix, the backdoor is initialised by the opening of hvc0 in root user. For a systemd guest machine, the following commands in the guest virtual machine should do the trick:

```
####################################
# systemd hvc0 for cloonix backdoor#
####################################
cd /lib/systemd/system
cp serial-getty@.service cloonix-getty@.service
sed -i s"%/sbin/agetty%/sbin/agetty -a root%" cloonix-getty@.service
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants
cd /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants
ln -s /lib/systemd/system/cloonix-getty@.service cloonix-   getty@hvc0.service
```

For an old machine with inittab, do:
      echo "T3:23:respawn:/sbin/agetty -a root -8 38400 hvc0"  >> /etc/inittab

Comment: For faster response on cloonix, just send a mail to the address in the source code, the answer should come back the same day.